# MPMoviePlayer in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayer

I have a html button in `UIWebView`, which on click pushes a `UIViewController` with programmed segue action. How to play a movie upon loading of the UIViewController with `MPMoviePlayer`. This code plays the Movie in `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead of the segue pushed `UIViewController`. I want to play the movie in the UIViewController pushed by segue.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"inapp"]) {
    if ([request.URL.host isEqualToString:@"capture"]) {

  [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueAction" sender: self];
  NSURL * urlA1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A1"ofType:@"mp4"]]; 
   MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontrollerA1 = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlA1];
        playercontrollerA1.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
           [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontrollerA1];
        playercontrollerA1.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;            
        // do capture action
    }
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) . You can add that as a subview of `self.view.`

**For eg:**

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[self.view addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

Fore more details please check the apple doc link above.

**Update:**

```
NSURL *urlA1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A1"ofType:@"mp4"]]; 
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlA1];
moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;            
// do capture action
```

Comment: I tried using the above - Xcode shows error - "use of undeclared item 'myView'". I declared myView as                                                          UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];

Comment: @Sivon, instead of `myView`, you should use your `self.view` or whichever view you want to add this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I put self.view in place of myView and added a UIview to the Viewcontroller in storyboards. Movie doesn't start. I don't know what to do next?

Comment: @Sivon, That was just a sample code. You need to use this approach along with your above code to make it work. Instead of `MPMoviePlayerViewController` use `MPMoviePlayerController` and do `[self.view addSubview: player.view];`. Rest of the things should be done similar to your question.

Comment: @Sivon, Are you still facing issues with this? I have updated my answer.

Comment: I used the updated code. A black screen appears in the View Controller without movie.

Comment: Comment this line `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueAction" sender: self];` and check if it is adding on current view.

Comment: "SegueAction" is pushing a ViewController with UIView (white screen) present in storyboards. This is happening in addition to the black screen I mentioned above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20918/discussion-between-acb-and-sivon)